# how patch api should work with partial correct and partial incorrect data?

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I have an patch api which accept billing and delivery address for an order. Http patch method is  used for this api.

Both address are correct only if they are provided completely like firstname, lastname, street, city, zip, country. If any of those fields are missing it would be considered as incomplete address hence invalid address which should be rejected by api.

the question is what should happen if request contain complete billing address and incomplete delivery address? should it accept billing address with warning message regarding incomplete delivery address or reject the request at all.

what is the standard practice to design api in this case?

Sample request body is like

```
{
    "invoiceAddress": {
        "salutation": "M",
        "firstName": "Dieter",
        "lastName": "Wolf",
        "companyName": "",
        "street": "Michaelkirchstr.",
        "houseNo": "16",
        "zipCode": "31604",
        "city": "Raddestorf",
        "countryIsoCode": "DEU",
        "phone": "05763 82 60 80",
        "email": "DieterWolf@armyspy.com"
    },
    "deliveryAddress": {
        "salutation": "M",
        "firstName": "Dieter",
        "lastName": "Wolf",
        "companyName": "",
        "street": "Michaelkirchstr.",
        "houseNo": "16",
        "zipCode": "31604 ",
        "countryIsoCode": "DEU",
        "phone": "05763 82 60 80",
        "email": "DieterWolf@armyspy.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb
The PATCH method is atomic.[1] Either all the changes specified by the PATCH method are applied or none of the changes are applied by the server

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789
PATCH is neither safe nor idempotent
The server MUST apply the entire set of changes atomically and never
provide (e.g., in response to a GET during this operation) a
partially modified representation.  If the entire patch document
cannot be successfully applied, then the server MUST NOT apply any of
the changes.